# Mock a MariaDB Socket connection for test purposes

Tags: mariadb, mysql-python, mariadb-connect-engine

I have been looking for a way to mock a MariaDB connection for test purposes.

The code I need to test opens a connection to a MariaDB server through unix socket.
All along the code, it updates rows.

The behavior I want to test has nothing to do with that is done with the database.

What service could I run in order to mock a MariaDB server that would accept every connection as well as insert or update queries without having to create databases, tables and so on ?

---

Note: The closest solution I could find was this
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_MYSQL_SERVER_MOCK.html

But it doesn't actually fit my purpose.